# Lucky 7 recursion

Tags: c++

Prompt: A lucky number is the number has the digit 7 and count of #7 in the number must be odd. Write a recursive function to check whether a number is lucky. (For example, lucky#: 777, 117, 7. not a lucky#: 77, 1277).

I am a beginner. I wrote the code below, but I don't understand how "if(num == 7) return 7" work although it should return a boolean. :(

Here is my code: (it checks if there is any digit 7 and sum off all digit 7 is odd)

```
bool lucky(int num)
{
    if (num < 10)
        if (num == 7) return 7; << HOW???? Please!
        else return 0;
    else if (num % 10 == 7)
        return (7 + lucky(num / 10)) % 2 != 0;
    else
        return lucky(num / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ any non-zero value can be considered "true", while zero is "false". Integers are [implicitly convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `bool` using this scheme.